# In JSDoc, is there a way to define terms in a separate file and link them within function docs?

Tags: jsdoc

What I would like is to write something like this:

```js
/**
 * Takes a foo and {@link grokelates} it.
 */
function doSomething(foo) {
}
```

And have "grokelates" be a link to more detail on what "grokelate" means, but because I'm going to have functions dealing with grokelation all over my code base, I'd like to write that definition once and link to it in multiple places.

Is this possible?

To be clear, grokelates is not a function. It's just a word I want to define, but not have to define in-line everywhere I use it. I basically want to write a glossary file and be able to link to definitions from that glossary in my JSDoc.

Ideally this would also be in a way the VS Code picks it up and lets someone navigate to that definition on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. When you run jsdoc to generate your documentation, you can pass it any filetype you wish. A standard practice is to create one or more *.jsdoc files which contain doclet comments (those that begin with `/**`) to describe features you expect to use elsewhere in your code. For instance:

```
// filename: grokelation.jsdoc
/**
 * @module grokelates
 */

/** 
 * @name Grokelate
 * @memberof module:grokelates
 * @description
 * Here is the description of the grokelation process. 
 *
 * @example
 * var g = new Grokelate(opts);
 */
```

Then, when you wish to reference this new object elsewhere in your documentation, simply use its long name `module:grokelates~Grokelate` where you can consider the `~` glyph to mean "member of".

In your example above, you'd say `{@link module:grokelates~Grokelate}`.

Comment: This seems to be the right direction, but I'm having trouble getting it to cooperate. In any event, it seems like VS Code ignores it too. 

Comment: When you run jsdoc, make sure you add the paths to your *.jsdoc files just as you do for your *.js files. (This is easier if you use a jsdoc config file along with the `-c` command line flag when you run jsdoc.)

Comment: And for how jsdoc integrates with VS Code, I'm afraid you're on your own. I find [atom](https://atom.io/) to be a far superior IDE for working with Node.